# Is the following algorithm lock-free?

Tags: parallel-processing, lock-free, locks

In my understanding, an algorithm is lock free if some thread always makes progress.

Now isn't this condition met by the following example (using locks):

Thread 1: using lock1 for critical section
Thread 2: using lock1 for critical section
Thread 3: some call independent of lock1 and the other two threads in general

Comment: *"using lock1 for cs"* ← What does that mean? What is "lock1", and what is "cs"?

Comment: Sorry, let me specify: lock1 is some lock which statisfies mutual exclusion. cs is some kind of critical section which might not ever terminate, making it possible to deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe certainly isn't "lock-free" in any meaningful sense. Thread 1 and 2 are dependent on the same shared resource (a critical section, enforced by "lock1"), so if one of them acquires that lock and then gets suspended, then the other thread will deadlock waiting on it.

Sure, Thread 3 will continue on unabated, but so will Thread A, B, and C (*i.e.*, threads that have nothing to do with your program). That seems to be irrelevant when looking at the algorithm as a whole, which presumably consists of all three threads.

Essentially, the problem with your definition of "lock-free" is that it isn't precise enough. You say that an algorithm is lock-free "if some thread always makes progress", but you fail to look at the algorithm as a whole.

Thread 3 is trivially lock-free (because it makes progress on its own, without the assistance of any other threads), but your overall algorithm is not.

A better way to assess whether an algorithm is lock-free is asking yourself: if a single thread gets suspended, will this prevent the other threads from making progress *as a group*? In this case, yes. If Thread 1 or Thread 2 acquires the lock and then gets suspended, this will prevent the other thread from executing, and presumably these other threads are doing work that is important to your algorithm.

I recommend [Jeff Preshing's blog post, "An Introduction to Lock-Free Programming"](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/). Here's a handy flow chart from that blog post:

[image: Are you programming with multiple threads? -> Yes -> Do the threads access shared memory? -> Yes -> Can the threads block each other? -> No -> It's lock-free programming!]

Comment: Thank you, I think the key point was about how I need to apply the progress criteria on the algorithm as a whole. The blog post you linked is very good as well.